# Use double.Parse that if Null value, then value replace with 0

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I'm trying to convert a string to a double. If it encounters null value the value should then be 0 (zero). However, it comes up with an error message:

"Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'. It's sort of confusing because both numbers are double? How do I fix this?

```
double final = double.Parse(min.ToString()) ?? 0.0;
```

Comment: What's the type of `min`? Can you share a complete example?

Comment: The reason for the error is that the left side of `??` has to be a nullable type. `double` can never be null, so it doesn't make sense to use `??` with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this, assuming `min` is a `string`:

```
double final = double.Parse(min ?? "0");
```

Or perhaps:

```
double final = (min == null) ? 0 : double.Parse(min);
```

**EDIT**

Even better:

```
double final = Convert.ToDouble(min);
```

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx), that method will return

> A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to the
>   number in value, **or 0 (zero) if value is null**.

Comment: Wow, thanks Smarx! It works :) I'll mark this as answered as soon as stack overflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because the left side of ?? must be a Nullable type that can take  **null** as a value.

in your code:

```
double final = double.Parse(min.ToString()) ?? 0.0;
```

You are using `??` operator which called [Null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and what this operator do is checking if `double.Parse(min.ToString())` __evaluates to a value has the type of `double` (which is a value type)_ is null or not. if it wasn't null, then assign the value to `final`, otherwise assigned `0.0` to it.

Since `double` is a value type and a value type variables cannot be null unless they are [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), you will get an error, and that's why you are getting this error:

"Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'double'."

To solve this, you can try this:

```
 double final = Convert.ToDouble(min);
```

which return zero if `min` was null.

PS: try to avoid using the `Parse` method, which throw `System.FormatExceptoin` when it fails to parse, use `TryParse` instead:

```
string min = "2.s"; // not a number
double finals;
bool successed =  double.TryParse(min, out finals); // true if successed, otherwise false.
Console.WriteLine(successed? $"Yes! finals =  {finals}": $"No :( finals =  {finals}");
// finals is 0 if the parse didn't work.
```